# Adding Latitude and Longitude to email Android

Tags: android, location

Basically, I'm trying to get the current Latitude & Longitude of the device, store it in a variable, and write that variable to a string with StringBuilder. Currently, the variable is returning null and i can't figure out why.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Ive got the permissions set in the Manifest, and my code is compiling fine.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        LocationManager locmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locListener);
 ...
}
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //Retrieve Latitude
            location.getLatitude();
            //retrieve longitude
            location.getLongitude();
            System.out.println(Latitude);
            System.out.println(Longitude);
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call

```
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();
```

to acquire the location. Those methods simply return the latitude and longitude values that are already stored in the location variable.

Right now, you are printing out the Latitude and Longitude variables before assigning them the actual coordinate values.

Try this:

```
@Override 
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
    Latitude = location.getLatitude(); //assuming Latitude and Longitude are of type double
    Longitude = location.getLongitude(); 
    System.out.println(Latitude);
    System.out.println(Longitude);


}
```

Comment: The `String.valueOf` is unnecessary here, since `println` accepts Objects just fine.

Comment: Good point. I've made it a personal habit to always use `String.valueOf()` so that I don't forget in cases where it matters.